# Implementing an initializer-list constructor that doesn't copy the elements

Tags: c++, c++14, initializer-list

I have a small Slice class that I use for functions that want to take a 'list' of items. It doesn't store any items, but is just a view into some existing list.

```
#include <initializer_list>

template<typename T>
struct Slice
{
    u32 length;
    T*  data;

    Slice(T& element) { length = 1; data = &element; }

    template<typename T, u32 Length>
    Slice(T(&arr)[Length]) { length = Length; data = arr; }

    inline T& operator [](u32 i) { return data[i]; }
};
```

I'm trying to make it possible to construct from an initializer list. Like so

```
Slice<i32> indices = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0 };
```

So I tried adding a constructor that takes an initializer_list

```
    template<typename T>
    Slice(std::initializer_list<T> initList) { length = initList.size(); data = (T*) initList.begin(); }
```

But, I think this is ill-formed because the `initializer_list` is a temporary value that will go out of scope after the assignment. Further, the Slice data is not strictly const and it appears that initializer_lists are.

Is there a proper way to implement this behavior?

Comment: Why do you want to be able to initialize the slice from an initializer list if it makes no sense?

Comment: Say I have a function that takes a Slice, and I want to pass an initializer list instead of explicitly creating an array/list before the call. `void Foo(Slice<int> bar) { ... }` then `Foo({1, 2, 3});`

Comment: Then why not disallow it by not having a `std::initializer_list` constructor?

Comment: I *want* that behavior

Comment: You can't take ownership of the initializer list's underlying array. That's a non-starter.

Comment: Why not to use a variable to hold an `initializer_list`? `auto x = {1, 2, 3}; Slice<i32> indices(x);`. Then it will be a view into `x`.

Comment: That's likely true. I may have been overzealous with my title. std:array allows initializer list syntax by copying the underlying data. I'm ok with copying the data for the intializer list case, but not for the other cases where it's not necessary.

Comment: There is some proposal for movable-from `initializer_list`: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4166.pdf. But its status is still _open_: https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-status.html

Comment: Ok, so copying is definitely the way to go. Now I have to figure out if it's possible to do that without needing a separate type. Seems unlikely though.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to copy those temporaries. You can use dynamic allocation in this case and a flag to signal the ownership:

```
template<typename T>
struct Slice
{
private:
    u32 length;
    T*  data;
    bool owns= false;

public:
    Slice(T& element) { length = 1; data = &element; }

    template<u32 Length>
    Slice(T(&arr)[Length]) { length = Length; data = arr; }

    Slice(std::initializer_list<T> initList): length(initList.size()), owns(true)
      { data= new T[length]; std::copy(initList.begin(),initList.end(),data); }

    ~Slice() { if (owns) delete[] data; }

    inline T& operator [](u32 i) { return data[i]; }
};
```